# Is it possible to convert Bitcoin Miner to Litecoin Miner?

Tags: hash, asic, mining-hardware

I have 90Gh/s Bitcoin Miner and its almost useless for Bitcoin Mining with current difficulty. By changing the Linux software installed in it can I convert this Bitcoin Miner to Litecoin Miner? I am capable on uninstalling/flashing the current operating system and re-install a new one but I am wondering is it just software that decides to mine only Bitcoin or hardware too supports only Bitcoin Mining?

If not possible with Litecoin Miner can I use this miner for mining any other crypto-currency?

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/19760/12983

Comment: @amaclin - Not complete answer, but slightly similar.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't. And this has nothing to do with the operating system. Your hardware has a bitcoin ASIC chip made only for doing Sha-256 calculations. Litecoin uses the Scrypt algorithm. Sha-256 and Scrypt are not the same, so what you are suggesting is impossible.

You can mine other Sha-256 coins instead of Bitcoin.

Comment: So, the miner can be still used to mine some other SHA-256 using coins? Do I need to do any software/hardware tweaks for this or will that work directly?

Comment: AFAIK you just have to enter a different command (different pool et cetera), no software changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. If you want to be a bit more profitable, you could try a different sha256 coin. Any coin using the sha256 algo can be mined with your miner.

Answer (score -1):

It is hardware bound. The above answer is correct. Another option is to rent out your hash-power and receive other cryptocoins.