# Can Scrypt be reduced to SHA256 proof of work?

Tags: proof-of-work

Interested because if a reducer exists then Bitcoin mining pools would be able to use a fraction of their hash power to assert dominance on altcoins by regularly deploying 51% attacks on the altcoins that rely on Scrypt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a bitcoin miner work for other currencies?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/19760/will-a-bitcoin-miner-work-for-other-currencies)

Comment: Understand that SHA256 miners don’t work on Skrypt today. I’m asking if a reduction from Scrypt to SHA256 is possible?